# Right settings for firewall rule C#

Tags: c#, firewall

I got a new question, what firewall settings is needed for blocking an IP address ? I found the property "RemoteAddress", like firewallRule.RemoteAddress, but I dont know how to use it. This is what I found on stackoverflow ( following code blocks all access to internet ), Thanks.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using NETCONLib;
using NATUPNPLib;
using NetFwTypeLib;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        INetFwRule firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(
        Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
        firewallRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
        firewallRule.Description = "Used to block all internet access.";
        firewallRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT;
        firewallRule.Enabled = true;
        firewallRule.InterfaceTypes = "All";
        firewallRule.Name = "Block Internet";

        INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(
        Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
        firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of ip addresses (subnets, aliases) splitted by commas

```
$Rule.RemoteAddresses = RemoteAddresses = 'LocalSubnet,10.1.1.1/255.255.255.255,12.5.0.0/255.255.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you have to retrieve the `RemoteAddresses` list first before adding to it. Otherwise, it just overwrites each IP with the next one. The format needs to be as Jan described in his/her answer. However, the subnet "`/255.255.255.255`" is not needed when adding a single IP address. My app only blocks a single ip at a time, but you can put ranges in there as Jan describes. Most the credit goes to others on SO with exception of the `RemoteAddresses` part. If there's a better/cleaner way, I would love to hear it. Here's how I ended up doing it:

```
        private void BlockIp(string ip, string ruleName)
        {
            INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
            INetFwRule firewallRule = firewallPolicy.Rules.OfType<INetFwRule>().Where(x => x.Name == ruleName).FirstOrDefault();

            if (firewallRule == null)
            {
                firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
                firewallRule.Name = ruleName;
                firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);
                firewallRule.Description = "Block inbound traffic";
                firewallRule.Profiles = (int)NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2_.NET_FW_PROFILE2_ALL;
                firewallRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP;
                firewallRule.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
                firewallRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
                //firewallRule.LocalPorts = "8080";
                //firewallRule.Grouping = "@firewallapi.dll,-23255";
                firewallRule.Enabled = true;
                firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = ip;
                //firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule); //throws error, not needed
            } else {
                var remoteAddresses = firewallRule.RemoteAddresses;
                firewallRule.RemoteAddresses = remoteAddresses + "," + ip;
            }
        }
```